# Hangman Game Bug

Tags: c

So this almost works, there's just a bug when entering the last character which it detects as a wrong character for some reason. I've tried debugging it in GDB but can't work out why this is happening

Also before anyone makes a comment about how this is all C code, our professor wants us to start with a C program then change it to C++ as we build it into a fully fledged game with graphics etc..

I am also aware there are better ways of structuring this with more functions, but getting it working is the priority at this stage

There is some commented out code strewn about which is just past attempts to get it working - feel free to ignore

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#define MAX_INPUT 1024

void updateAvailableLetters(char *_arrAvailableLetters[0], char _currentLetter);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 0)
    {
        srand(time(NULL)); //seeds the rand() function with the number of seconds since epoch date so rand() will change
    }
    else
    {
        srand((int)argv[1]); //seeds the rand() function with the command line argument
    }


    const char arrLetters[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}; //array of letters to be used
    char *arrLettersMem = (char*)malloc(strlen(arrLetters)+1); //memory for strcpy
    char *arrAvailableLetters[] = {strcpy(arrLettersMem, arrLetters)}; //array of available letters which will be updated
    const char *arrWordList[] = {"hello", "goodbye", "this", "is", "a", "game"}; //array of secret words
    int iWordCount = sizeof(arrWordList)/sizeof(arrWordList[0]); //number of words in the array

    printf("This is my hangman game. Please guess a letter to avoid the hangman!\n");

    while (true) //main game loop
    {
        const char *pCurrentWord = arrWordList[rand() % iWordCount]; //randomly select a word
        int iWordLength = strlen(pCurrentWord); //selected word length
        char *pCurrentWordMem = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*pCurrentWord * iWordLength)); //pointer to the dynamically allocated memory 
        char *pCurrentWordCopy = strcpy(pCurrentWordMem, pCurrentWord); //copy of selected word
        char *pBlankWord = (char*) memset(pCurrentWordCopy,'-',iWordLength); //letters found so far
        int iLettersGuessed = 0; //number of correct guesses
        int iWrongGuessesLeft = 8;
        bool inWord = false;


        while(iWrongGuessesLeft > 0 && iLettersGuessed != iWordLength)
        {
            printf("\n");
            char c;
            while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
                char currentLetter = tolower(c); 
                inWord = false;
                if (strchr(arrLetters, currentLetter) == NULL) //quick validation
                {
                    printf("Please try a letter from a-z!\n");
                    break;
                }

                // char compare = *strchr(arrAvailableLetters[0], currentLetter);
                // if (strchr(arrAvailableLetters[0], currentLetter) != NULL){
                if (strchr(arrAvailableLetters[0], currentLetter) == NULL){ //is the current letter already chosen?
                    {
                        printf("You have already chosen %c, guess again!\n", currentLetter);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //is the currentLetter in the chosen word?
                    for (int i = 0; i < iWordLength - 1; i++){
                        if(currentLetter == pCurrentWord[i]){
                            pBlankWord[i] = currentLetter;
                            iLettersGuessed++;
                            updateAvailableLetters(arrAvailableLetters, currentLetter);
                            printf("*** CORRECT GUESS *** - %c IS in the word!\n", currentLetter);
                            printf("Guess a letter for the word: %s\n", pBlankWord);
                            printf("You have %d guesses left, and have guessed %d letters so far.\n", iWrongGuessesLeft, iLettersGuessed);
                            printf("Available letters are: %s\n", arrAvailableLetters[0]);
                            inWord = true;
                    }
                }

                if (inWord == false){
                    // for (int j = 0; j < iWordLength - 1; j++){
                    //     if(currentLetter != pCurrentWord[j]){
                            iWrongGuessesLeft--;
                            updateAvailableLetters(arrAvailableLetters, currentLetter);
                            // *strchr(arrAvailableLetters[0], currentLetter) = '.'; //update available letters
                            printf("!!! WRONG GUESS !!! - %c IS NOT in the word!\n", currentLetter);
                            printf("Guess a letter for the word: %s\n", pBlankWord);
                            printf("You have %d wrong guesses left, and have guessed %d letters so far.\n", iWrongGuessesLeft, iLettersGuessed);
                            printf("Available letters are: %s\n", arrAvailableLetters[0]);
                    //     }
                    // }
                }
            }



            // if (currentLetter == *pCurrentWord) //is the currentLetter in the currentWord
            // {
            //     *pBlankWord = currentLetter;
            //     iLettersGuessed++;
            //     for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){ //updates arrAvailableLetters with '.'
            //         if (arrAvailableLetters[0][i] == currentLetter){
            //             arrAvailableLetters[0][i] = '.';
            //             break;
            //         }
            //     }
            //     // *strchr(arrAvailableLetters[0], currentLetter) = '.'; //update available letters
            //     printf("*** CORRECT GUESS *** - %c IS in the word!\n", currentLetter);
            //     printf("Guess a letter for the word: %s\n", pBlankWord);
            //     printf("You have %d guesses left, and have guessed %d letters so far.\n", iWrongGuessesLeft, iLettersGuessed);
            //     printf("Available letters are: %s\n", arrAvailableLetters[0]);
            //     pCurrentWord++;
            // }
            // else
            // {
            //     iWrongGuessesLeft--;
            //     for (int q = 0; q < 26; q++){
            //         if (arrAvailableLetters[0][q] == currentLetter){
            //             arrAvailableLetters[0][q] = '.';
            //             break;
            //         }
            //     }
            //     // *strchr(arrAvailableLetters[0], currentLetter) = '.'; //update available letters
            //     printf("!!! WRONG GUESS !!! - %c IS NOT in the word!\n", currentLetter);
            //     printf("Guess a letter for the word: %s\n", pBlankWord);
            //     printf("You have %d wrong guesses left, and have guessed %d letters so far.\n", iWrongGuessesLeft, iLettersGuessed);
            //     printf("Available letters are: %s\n", arrAvailableLetters[0]);
            // }
            // }

        }

        free(pCurrentWordMem); 
        free(arrLettersMem);

        char buffer[MAX_INPUT];
        if (iWrongGuessesLeft == 0)
        {
            printf("Oh no, you got hanged! Do you want to try again y/n?");
            while (fgets(buffer,MAX_INPUT,stdin) != NULL)
            {
                if (buffer[0] == 'y' || buffer[0] == 'Y') 
                    break;
                else if (buffer[0] == 'n' || buffer[0] == 'N') 
                {
                    return 0;
                } 
                else 
                    printf("Enter (y/n)\n");
            }
        }

        if (iLettersGuessed == iWordLength)
        {
            printf("Congratulations, you guessed the word! Do you want to try again y/n?");
            while (fgets(buffer,MAX_INPUT,stdin) != NULL)
            {
                if (buffer[0] == 'y' || buffer[0] == 'Y') 
                    break;
                else if (buffer[0] == 'n' || buffer[0] == 'N') 
                {
                    return 0;
                } 
                else 
                    printf("Enter (y/n)\n");
            }
        }    
    }
}

void updateAvailableLetters(char *_arrAvailableLetters[0], char _currentLetter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){ //updates arrAvailableLetters with '.'
            if (_arrAvailableLetters[0][i] == _currentLetter){
                _arrAvailableLetters[0][i] = '.';
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: you should learn how to add debug printfs if you cant step through in gdb.  If you fixed a word instead of having it be random, and saw iWordLen of "hello" was 5 you wouldnt have used iWordLength -1 and missed the last letter.

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iWordLength - 1; i++){
```

`iWordLength` was previously set to `strlen(pCurrentWord)`, and you want to iterate over all letters in the word. The above code will only iterate up to the penultimate letter. Change the conditional to

```
for (int i = 0; i < iWordLength; i++){
```